# How to remove a docker image will multiple tags in single command?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have two docker images with tags as `dockerimage:test` and `dockerimage:<none>`. How can I remove both of these images with a single command?

Answer (score 0):

> Docker doesn't allow `*` to remove images using wildcard

Get image id's with

```
docker images // or docker images -a
```

and then run

```
docker rmi imageId1 imageId2 imageId13
```

Comment: I need to remove them in an automation. How can I get the image IDs to pass to the next command?

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images | awk '$1=="dockerimage" && ($2=="test" || $2=="<none>") {print $3}')`

Answer (score 0):

I used the command below to remove all images.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "reference=dockerimage" -q)
```